# MVC4/IIS7 Error 500 diagnostics. No stack trace, no event log

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 project which worked fine on the (IIS7) server. Then I moved to a new laptop, so of course all the NuGet packages I'd installed had to be uninstalled and reinstalled with different versions in order to get it to build (all I'm using is dotless and whatever dependencies it has, but that appears to be more than nuget was ever designed to cope with).

It now works fine again on my new laptop, but on the server all it does is give me an Error 500. No stack trace. There's nothing in the event log on the server. I set up Failed Request Tracing but the log file directory is empty.

I created a file on the server called test.html:

```
<p>test</p>
```

That can't be served either. Error 500 again. Nothing in the failed request log directory, nothing in the event log.

Everything else on that site on that server works fine.

So my question is: Is there any known way to set about diagnosing a situation like this?

UPDATE

It turns out I misconfigured Failed Request Tracing, and had it only enabled for *.aspx. When it's enabled for *, I do get fr00000?.xml in inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC1, one for each failed request.

The problem turns out to have been something broken in web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I misconfigured Failed Request Tracing, and had it only enabled for *.aspx. Once I had it enabled for *, then for each failed request a sequentially numbered log file was created:

```
inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC1\fr00000?.xml
```

...etc. Those files contain a staggering amount of detail.

I searched for "exception" in that xml, and the problem turned out to have been something broken in web.config

So this was pure stupidity on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some configuration issue with the site and how it's set up in IIS. Without being at your computer, it's hard to say with any certainty, but my best guess based on experience is that you've got a permissions issue with the directory that's being used as the docroot of the site. Make sure IIS_IUSERS has at least read and execute access to that directory.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Actually IIS_IUSERS doesn't seem to have access to anything in that inetpub -- but it all works fine.